# Sometimes html height:100% doesn't fill the whole window

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I got a header and a editable content box with this **css**:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header {
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background: wheat;
}
.content {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    width: 80%;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    overflow: scroll;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="content" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

**[jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/zhouxiaoping/4cwzbc7t/1/)**

When the scrollbar of the `content` shows up, then click the return key, and the html will not fill the page anymore.

**here is the picture that shows what is happening:**
[image]

As you can see, the html is about 10px cut.
This also happens on my two friends computer every time They do as I have said just now, but it has never happened on my computer and we are under the same environment.

**The environment:**
mac pro, chrome version:42.0 (not happened in safari)

**What I did:**
When I try to add `position: fixed` to html element, it works ,and the problem disappear

**My problem:**
I want to know, is it a bug of chrome? why `position: fixed`can fix it,and what happened?

In my real project, the body is `{margin: 0}`, but the problem still happened, but the demo works fine if it has `body{margin: 0}`, I am confused.

Comment: in my real project,the body has ```{margin: 0}```, and my header of website will be cut by 10px

Comment: Setting the body-margin to zero will solve this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4cwzbc7t/4/

Comment: The { height: calc(100% - 100px); } is wrong. You have to take the border and the padding in account. See the box model http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: the box-sizing is border-box

Comment: @super-xp in that case, can you show the ___complete___ css, so that we don't have to guess? Or better still, create an example, for instance in http://jsfiddle.net that demonstrates the issue.